Comparing two different time ranges on the same panel?
I have a panel that shows average AWS ECS CPU usage, as per screenshot. I would like to be able to compare that data between 2 week sprints - have it show current data vs last 2 weeks for example, in the same panel, or first 2 weeks of August vs last 2 weeks of August. That's the point. How would I do this? This is a cloudwatch plugin I'm using, running AWS managed Grafana, 10.4. Thanks.
I asked around and was told about offsets, but I couldn't find that option. Then there was a CompareQuery plugin I was recommended, but its not in the plugin store for me.
Edit: I want 2 different time ranges but same time - now, 9am for example, vs 9am, 2 weeks ago.

